# Excel VBA - Check Values in Sheet1 Against Sheet2, then Copy Notes If Matching

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets. I want to check the value in one column against the value in the same column in the second sheet. If they match, then I want to migrate the string data from the Notes column to the new sheet. (essentially I'm seeing if last week's ticket numbers are still valid this week, and carrying over the notes from last week).

I am trying to do this with the following code (using columns Z for the data, BE for the notes):

```
Sub Main()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim partNo2 As Range
Dim partNo1 As Range
Dim partNo3 As Range


For Each partNo2 In ws1.Range("Z1:Z" & ws1.Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each partNo1 In ws2.Range("Z1:Z" & ws2.Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
     For Each partNo3 In ws1.Range("BE1:BE" & ws2.Range("BE" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If StrComp(Trim(partNo2), Trim(partNo1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ws2.Range("BE" & partNo1.Row) = partNo3
        End If
        Next
    Next
Next

'now if no match was found then put NO MATCH in cell
For Each partNo1 In ws2.Range("E1:F" & ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If IsEmpty(partNo1) Then partNo1 = ""
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is up with column E and F?

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim c As Range, f As Range

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("Z1:Z" & ws1.Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("Z1:Z" & ws2.Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each c In rng1.Cells
        Set f = rng2.Find(c.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            f.EntireRow.Cells(, "BE").Value = c.EntireRow.Cells(, "BE").Value
        End If
    Next c

    'now if no match was found then put NO MATCH in cell
    For Each c In ws2.Range("E1:F" & ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then c.Value = "NO MATCH"
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This accomplishes the same result (maybe with the exception of the columns E & F at the bottom with NO MATCH).  It's just a different way of going about it.  Instead of using ranges, I'm just looking at each cell and comparing it directly.

**TESTED:**

```
Sub NoteMatch()

Dim lastRow1 As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim tempVal As String

    lastRow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lastRow2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    For sRow = 2 To lastRow1
        tempVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(sRow, "Z").Text

        For tRow = 2 To lastRow2
            If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(tRow, "Z") = tempVal Then
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(tRow, "BE") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(sRow, "BE")
            End If
        Next tRow
    Next sRow

Dim match As Boolean
'now if no match was found, then put NO MATCH in cell
    For lRow = 2 To lastRow2
        match = False
        tempVal = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lRow, "Z").Text

        For sRow = 2 To lastRow1
            If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(sRow, "Z") = tempVal Then
                match = True
            End If
        Next sRow

        If match = False Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(lRow, "BE") = "NO MATCH"
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]